# Why do we write dots (.) in path.resolve()?

Tags: node.js

The code shown below are examples used to explain `path.resolve()` on https://nodejs.org/api/path.html

```
path.resolve('/foo/bar', './baz');
// Returns: '/foo/bar/baz'

path.resolve('/foo/bar', '/tmp/file/');
// Returns: '/tmp/file'

path.resolve('wwwroot', 'static_files/png/', '../gif/image.gif');
// If the current working directory is /home/myself/node,
// this returns '/home/myself/node/wwwroot/static_files/gif/image.gif'
```

I noticed that all dots are just omited.
`./baz` is converted to `baz` in the first example.
`../gif/image.gif` is converted to `/gif/image.gif` in the 3rd example.
Then, why bother writing these dots? 
What would happen if these dots didn't exist in the two examples?
Thx!

Comment: Why don't you just try it yourself?  A simple test script of a couple lines will show you the answer to your question about what happens.  Personally, I've almost never found a use for `path.resolve()`.  I use `path.join()` and a few others, but have found no need for `path.resolve()`  It's just funky how it can completely ignore some things you pass it.

Answer (score 0):

The path.resolve() method is used to resolve a sequence of path-segments to an absolute path.

It works by processing the sequence of paths from right to left, prepending each of the paths until the absolute path is created. The resulting path is normalized and trailing slashes are removed as required.

If no path segments are given as parameters, then the absolute path of the current working directory is used.

The passed argument is a series of file paths that would be resolved together to form an **absolute path**.

Comment: It doesn't just join them together and turn it into an absolute path though.  If you pass it three args like this: `path.resolve('/foo', '/bar', 'baz')`, you end up with `/bar/baz` (completely ignoring the `/foo`.  I've never found a need for this kind of weird functionality.  If you can explain how that example solves some useful problem, I'd love to hear it.